# No main function error about maxMind

Tags: java, geo, maxmind

I have a problem about maxmind API. I use some example to test. However, the runtime error "no main function  public static void main(String[] args)" 
I am confused that I have `public static void main` already.

```
public class GetLocationExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            LookupService lookup = new LookupService("D:\\GeoLiteCity.dat\\GeoLiteCity.dat",LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
            Location locationServices = lookup.getLocation("140.118.175.207");
            System.out.println("# country code: " + locationServices.countryCode);
            System.out.println("# country name: " + locationServices.countryName);
            lookup.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Provide more info. We are no magicians. If you want us to help you, show us what you've got.

Comment: You have `public static void main` but do you have `public static void main(String [] args)` ?Are you sure you have the same declaration method with the same parameter ?

Comment: If your main method is correct, that leaves a handful of other possibilities. Maybe you haven't compiled the file properly, or you're trying to run the wrong class?

Comment: sorry, i can't  understand this platform very much ..

Comment: I mean that i have main function and no complie error, but i get rum time error that say i have no main function in my class

Answer (score 0):

You certainly just have to add `String[]` parameter to your main method :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // The content of your main method
}
```